# pytest-django: allow test to update database

Tags: django, pytest-django

I have a lot of little "tests" I use manually, that is, I run them on demand. Some of them I want to alter the database. I have for a long time used pytest for these. (situation is caching production data in dev environment for some specific testing and debugging)

I have been convinced to add pytest-django, which has some great features.
It has hijacked my ad-hoc tests; immediately, they can't access or update the database.

Database access and allowing updates is documented and I was quickly able to half solve it: enable database access, update the database during the test. But all my changes are backed out.

My solution to do that may be bad, well obviously it only half works.

I have added this file: conftest.py in what seems to be the correct place (same directory as the tests).

with contents:

```
import pytest
from django.conf import settings

pytest_plugins = [
    "tests.fixtures.environments",
    "tests.fixtures.initial_data",
]
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def django_db_setup():
    settings.DATABASES["default"] = {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': 'django_api_sync',
        'PASSWORD': 'devpassword',
        'NAME': 'django_api_sync',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
    settings.DATABASES["dear_analytics"] ={
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'USER': 'django_api_sync',
        'PASSWORD': 'devpassword',
        'NAME': 'dear_analytics',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432,
    }



@pytest.fixture
def db_no_rollback(request, django_db_blocker):
    django_db_blocker.unblock()
    request.addfinalizer(django_db_blocker.restore)
```

and then I decorate my test for example:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
def test_summarise_next_available_data(db_no_rollback):
    KeyValueJson.objects.update_or_create(object_uniqueID="aaa_dear_last_sales_update", defaults={"value": "2020-01-01T00:00:00Z"})
    row = KeyValueJson.objects.filter(object_uniqueID="aaa_dear_last_sales_update").first()
    print(row.value) # this works as expected
```

...

It runs just fine. During execution, it accesses and updates the database, but the database changes are never committed and they are backed out. If I stop execution at the breakpoint and then query the postgresql table, there is no such row. So it looks like there is a transaction going on, and it is being rolled back.

EDIT

Ah, the test works if I remove  @pytest.mark.django_db

or if I do

@pytest.mark.django_db(transaction=True)

I don't understand why either of these have this effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it works when you remove the marker because django tests already have the database access without the marker:

> Test classes that subclass django.test.TestCase will have access to
> the database always to make them compatible with existing Django
> tests. Test classes that subclass Python’s unittest.TestCase need to
> have the marker applied in order to access the database.

When you add the marker without specifying Transaction=True, the Transaction is set to False by default:

> With transaction=False (the default when not specified), transaction
> operations are noops during the test.

Reference: https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#pytest.mark.django_db